# How to configure Microsoft Exchange Server (i.e my company's server) to Outlook 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, outlook-2003, mailbox

I am not able to find the Microsoft Exchange's Server name given the userid.  Where could I find it?

When I visit the mailbox through the browser, I specify the user name and password.  I am not able to find the Microsoft Exchange server name through here. I visited `Options->About` in the mailbox, but I only see this:

```
Microsoft Exchange Server @ 2007
Microsoft Outlook @ 2003
```

My company email address is: `abc.def@company.com`, The server for that is Microsoft Exchange Server @ 2007.  On the browser it prompts me for a username/password, which is a Microsoft exchange's server login page. I want to configure outlook 2003 for this mail server and I need the exchange server name.

Comment: Do you have physical access to this machine? Sorry, I will try to help if no one else does, but I am having problems understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the IT department for your organization? It seems like a pretty simple question for them to answer and an almost impossible one for us without knowing your company's setup.

Comment: clearly an end user question. How did we miss this before?

Answer (score 1):

If your company has enabled the RPC over HTTP Option for the Exchange server then you can use Outlook remotely.  If they have not (it is not enabled by default) then you can not use Outlook and you'll need to continue to use Outlook Web Access (that's what the website you are using is called).

In Outlook click on Tools then Accounts.  Add a new account.  Select Microsoft Exchange and click Next.  Select Microsoft Exchange again and select Next.  Click on More Settings.  On the general tab type in a name for the Account (Exchange, Work, etc).

On the Connection tab check the Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP and click the Exchange Proxy Settings button.

On the new window type in the URL for the Website that you currently use for accessing your mailbox without any folder names.  It'll be something like webmail.yourcompany.com or mail.yourcompany.com, etc.  Check the connect using SSL only.  In the proxy authentication drop down select the NTLM authentication option.  Click ok, and the ok again.

On the new account screen you'll need to enter the name of the Exchange server.  You can try entering the name of the website site, and in the User Name field enter your username to log onto the web mail.  Click the Check Name box and see if it finds your mailbox.

You may need to play with the authentication settings, and you may need to know the actual name of the Exchange server to make this work.

Keep in mind this might not work at all because RCP over HTTP is disabled.  Your best bet would be to ask your company mail admin or help desk if using Outlook to access Exchange from home is supported or not.  They would be able to provide instructions specific to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

RB,  Your company's helpdesk should be able to give you the configuration parameter, or even if you can configure Outlook in your scenario.  Some companies only allow OWA (the internet URL you use) outside the firewall.  So Outlook only works on the LAN, and through VPNs.  Other companies enable HTTP/RPC, IMAP, or POP/SMTP over the internet so Outlook will work outside the firewall, but you need to know the name of the server(s) to configure it.
If you are on LAN,  you could get an idea of the settings by looking at another PC's settings.  Outlook 2007 will attempt to autodiscover the correct settings, but I don't think Outlook 2003 will.